# error msg getting Subquery returned more than 1 value. what is the error in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO [BOOnboardingStatus]
            (BusinessID,
             SectionID,
             SectionName,
             SubSectionID,
             SubSectionName,
             status,
             createdby,
             modifieddate,
             modifiedby,
             source,
             createddate)
SELECT contentid,
       2,
       'Additional Info',
       '22',
       'Add keywords',
       (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN categoryname IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END
        FROM   businesscategory
        WHERE  businessid IN(SELECT contentid
                             FROM   businessmaster
                             WHERE  isclaim = 1)
               AND [primary] = 1),
       1,
       Getdate(),
       0,
       'BOD',
       Getdate()
FROM   businessmaster
WHERE  isclaim = 1
```

Comment: You have just one sub-query and the error message is pretty clear

Comment: @Pரதீப், Almost correct, actually there are two sub-queries...

Comment: @jarlh - Fine :/ The `IN` operator made me not to consider ..

Comment: I am not sure, but can't you use `CASE WHEN EXISTS(...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in `status` column?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT contentid, 2, 'Additional Info', '22', 'Add keywords',
       (SELECT CASE WHEN categoryname IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
               END
        FROM businesscategory bc
        WHERE bc.businessid = bm.contentid AND
              bc.[primary] = 1
       ),
       1, Getdate(), 0, 'BOD', Getdate()
FROM businessmaster bm
WHERE isclaim = 1 ;
```

EDIT:

Perhaps `EXISTS` does what you want.  It definitely will get rid of the error:

```
SELECT contentid, 2, 'Additional Info', '22', 'Add keywords',
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM businesscategory bc
                          WHERE bc.businessid = bm.contentid AND
                          bc.[primary] = 1
                         )
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END),
       1, Getdate(), 0, 'BOD', Getdate()
FROM businessmaster bm
WHERE isclaim = 1 ;
```

Comment: @sonuods, then do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: @sonuods . . . Then you have multiple "primary" flags on a single "businessid" in "businesscategory".